# PyCharm changed python files icon

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm very new in programming languages and I'm learning Python. I tried to install PyCharm to make my life easier but I noticed my python files *(.py)* changed the icon when I installed it, this is really annoying me, I like the old icon! How can I change back to the older one?

Comment: You can go to file properties and change program which opens it

Comment: Oh, just this? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the Pycharm is your default program to open (.py) files

**Solution:**

Go to the file properties and under general tab change the "Opens with" option as desired.